# Creating a gradient in background with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, gradient, pdfbox

How can I create a gradient in PDFBox? Or maybe "can I?".

I don't want to create them and export to jpeg or something else. I need a light document, so this has to be programmed somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of gradient do you want? Axial or radial? What bounds? What colors? Have you tried the CreateGradientShadingPDF.java from the source code download?

Comment: It looks like I don't have it in my jar downloaded from the website. Should I download it from the external website?

Comment: It should be in the source download. If not, then get it here https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreateGradientShadingPDF.java?view=markup&sortby=date

Comment: I just looked, it is also in the source download zip, at pdfbox-2.0.3\examples\src\main\java\org\apache\pdfbox\examples\pdmodel

Comment: I think I'm getting this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you want, you can answer the question yourself, assuming that your answer is more "real world" than the example. If you have any improvement suggestion or //comments to improve the example, don't hesitate to tell it here (put "@Tilman Hausherr" so that I get pinged) or in the PDFBox user mailing list.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have a small problem with understanding the creation of a gradient. What I understood is: on your document, you create COSDictionary object. Documentation doesn't tell me much, to be honest. There's nothing specific there. "This class represents a dictionary where name/value pairs reside." Maybe I can't find/get it. Then you set some int in this object. Then you create COSArrays, add some integers there, use methode setItem() (This will set an item in the dictionary. If value is null then...). Not specific. Could you explain how does creating a gradient work in this library?

Comment: It is explained in the PDF 32000 specification https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf , both the structures, and the gradients (look for "shading dictionaries", then type 2 or 3 - you still haven't decided which one you want). The question you just asked are about the PDF structures in general (dictionary, array). It might help to look at a PDF file with PDFBox PDFDebugger.... the steps in the example mirror the PDF specification. The c0 and c1 arrays are the upper and lower RGB colors. The "coords" variables are the coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research, I finally created a small "creator of my own gradient"! It looks like this:

```
COSDictionary fdict = new COSDictionary();

fdict.setInt(COSName.FUNCTION_TYPE, 2); // still not understaning that...

COSArray domain = new COSArray();
domain.add(COSInteger.get(0));
domain.add(COSInteger.get(1));

COSArray c0 = new COSArray();
c0.add(COSFloat.get("0.64176"));
c0.add(COSFloat.get("0.72588"));
c0.add(COSFloat.get("0.78078"));

COSArray c1 = new COSArray();
c1.add(COSFloat.get("0.57176"));
c1.add(COSFloat.get("0.62588"));
c1.add(COSFloat.get("0.70078"));

fdict.setItem(COSName.DOMAIN, domain);
fdict.setItem(COSName.C0, c0);
fdict.setItem(COSName.C1, c1);
fdict.setInt(COSName.N, 1);

PDFunctionType2 func = new PDFunctionType2(fdict);

PDShadingType2 axialShading = new PDShadingType2(new COSDictionary());

axialShading.setColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
axialShading.setShadingType(PDShading.SHADING_TYPE2);

COSArray coords1 = new COSArray();
coords1.add(COSInteger.get(0));
coords1.add(COSInteger.get(0));
coords1.add(COSInteger.get(850)); // size of my page
coords1.add(COSInteger.get(600));

axialShading.setCoords(coords1); // so this sets the bounds of my gradient
axialShading.setFunction(func); // and this determines all the curves etc?

CStr.shadingFill(axialShading); // where CStr is a ContentStream for my PDDocument
```

I will leave this for others. Leave your opinions and be free to show me some clever ideas to improve this code :)

Comment: The function calculates the color (here: RGB colorspace, but it could also be CMYK or whatever) from the input value on the axis. The type 2 function is an Exponential Interpolation function and is the most common used. It is explained in 7.10.3 of the PDF specification. Just imagine that the result values go between the two bounds C0 and C1, it isn't really needed to understand the math.

Comment: I got an idea, that these values of color between 0-1 are proportional to these between 0-255 in RGB. That got me closer. That's a pretty useful library, I like it!!

Comment: Yes indeed. In PDF colors are between 0 and 1. So 1 0 0 is a perfect red.

Comment: What would be your solution for drawing a triangle? I can only find codes, which use deprecated methodes, such as appendRawCommands(). "q\n" or "B*\n" don't tell me much...

Comment: use moveTo(), LineTo(), LineTo(), closePath(), stroke(). Don't forget to set a stroking color.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class I made to make the creation of gradients easier. It supports axial gradients with multiple colors. It uses `java.awt.Color` to specify colors but that can be replaced easily.

```java
public class PDGradient extends PDShadingType2 {

    public PDGradient(List<GradientPart> parts) {
        super(new COSDictionary());

        // PDF 1.7 - 8.7.4.5.3 Type 2 (Axial) Shadings
        setColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
        setShadingType(PDShadingType2.SHADING_TYPE2);
        setFunction(createGradientFunction(parts));
    }

    private static PDFunction createGradientFunction(List<GradientPart> parts) {
        if (parts.size() < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gradient must have at least 2 colors.");
        }

        GradientPart first = parts.get(0);
        GradientPart last = parts.get(parts.size() - 1);
        if (first.ratio != 0f) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gradient first color ratio must be 0.");
        } else if (last.ratio != 1f) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gradient last color ratio must be 1.");
        }
        if (parts.size() == 2) {
            // Only two colors, use exponential function.
            return createColorFunction(first.color, last.color);
        }

        // Multiple colors, use stitching function to combine exponential functions
        // PDF 1.7 - 7.10.4 Type 3 (Stitching) Functions
        COSDictionary dict = new COSDictionary();
        COSArray functions = new COSArray();
        COSArray bounds = new COSArray();
        COSArray encode = new COSArray();
        GradientPart lastPart = first;
        for (int i = 1; i < parts.size(); i++) {
            GradientPart part = parts.get(i);

            // Add exponential function for interpolating between these two colors.
            functions.add(createColorFunction(lastPart.color, part.color));

            // Specify function bounds, except for first and last, which are specified by domain.
            if (i != parts.size() - 1) {
                bounds.add(new COSFloat(part.ratio));
            }

            // Used to interpolate stitching function subdomain (eg: [0.2 0.5] 
            // to the exponential function domain, which is always [0.0 1.0].
            encode.add(COSInteger.ZERO);
            encode.add(COSInteger.ONE);

            lastPart = part;
        }

        dict.setInt(COSName.FUNCTION_TYPE, 3);
        dict.setItem(COSName.DOMAIN, new PDRange());  // [0.0 1.0]
        dict.setItem(COSName.FUNCTIONS, functions);
        dict.setItem(COSName.BOUNDS, bounds);
        dict.setItem(COSName.ENCODE, encode);

        return new PDFunctionType3(dict);
    }

    private static PDFunction createColorFunction(Color start, Color end) {
        // PDF 1.7 - 7.10.3 Type 2 (Exponential Interpolation) Functions
        COSDictionary dict = new COSDictionary();
        dict.setInt(COSName.FUNCTION_TYPE, 2);
        dict.setItem(COSName.DOMAIN, new PDRange());  // [0.0 1.0]
        dict.setItem(COSName.C0, createColorCOSArray(start));
        dict.setItem(COSName.C1, createColorCOSArray(end));
        dict.setInt(COSName.N, 1);  // Linear interpolation
        return new PDFunctionType2(dict);
    }

    private static COSArray createColorCOSArray(Color color) {
        // Create a COSArray for a color. 
        // java.awt.Color uses 0-255 values while PDF uses 0-1.
        COSArray a = new COSArray();
        a.add(new COSFloat(color.getRed() / 255f));
        a.add(new COSFloat(color.getGreen() / 255f));
        a.add(new COSFloat(color.getBlue() / 255f));
        return a;
    }

    /**
     * Specifies a color and its position in a {@link PDGradient}.
     */
    public static class GradientPart {

        public final Color color;
        public final float ratio;

        public GradientPart(Color color, float ratio) {
            this.color = color;
            this.ratio = ratio;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```java
List<GradientPart> parts = new ArrayList<>();
parts.add(new GradientPart(Color.RED, 0.0f));
parts.add(new GradientPart(Color.YELLOW, 0.5f));
parts.add(new GradientPart(Color.GREEN, 1.0f));
PDGradient gradient = new PDGradient(parts);
gradient.setCoords(...);
pdfStream.shadingFill(gradient)
```

This works essentially the same as the other answer for two colors gradients, using an exponential function (type 2) to linearly interpolate between two colors. If there are more colors, a stitching (type 3) function is used to combine multiple exponential functions with different subdomains.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use this to create a gradient, on my page-footer by:

pdfStream.addRect(0, 0, pageWidth, 20f)
pdfStream.clip()

However, how do I undo the clipping area to be able to draw to the whole page? I tried everything I can come up with but none of them worked.

Comment: Found the answer from Adobe PDF Reference. You need to call saveGraphicsState() before and restoreGraphicsState() after clipping&drawing.